# How to bind event with dynamic value generated through ajax in jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am having a problem with dynamic generated checkbox. I have tried like this :

```
<select name="model" id="model" class="" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="1">iPhone 5</option>
<option value="2">Iphone 4S</option>
<option value="3">Iphone 4</option>
</select>
```

Based on above selected value these checkbox will generated through ajax.Here are the element generated through ajax:

```
<p><input type="checkbox" id="screenguard" name="screenguard" value="20" />Cover</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="Charger" name="Charger" value="30" />Charger</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="hdphdm" name="hdphdm" value="10" />Headphone</p>

<p>
 Calculated Price: <input type="text" name="price" id="price" />
</p>
```

And based on selection made of checkboxes I need to calculate the value in to another input box(price) . Here is my Jquery function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"]')
    $inputs.on('change', function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $inputs.each(function() {
        // iterate and add it to sum only if checked
           if(this.checked)
               sum += parseInt(this.value);
        });
        $("#price").val(sum);

    });
});
```

But I don't know why it's not working. Please give me any suggestion, what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [event delegatio](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)n like this -

```
$(document.body).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
```

Comment: I already tried this, but it's not working , I don't know why?

Comment: @Toretto retry using this exact same syntax, should work

Comment: Ok, It's working now , I did a silly mistake and figured it out. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score -1):

Every time you click a checkbox 'sum' is reset back to zero. Move it outside of the 'change' event.